# How to hide a fixed element if outside of it's parent element's height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to know how I can hide the `.fixedElement` that is within the `.entry-content` not allowing it to show over the `.header(blue section)` or `.footer(green section)`, once the .fixedElement reaches top/bottom of it's parent element it hides it.

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/cafgnzj3/

I learned that fixed elements does not behave within it's parent element css styles because it is based on the viewport of the browser.

I thought it would be a lot easier to create an example.

I'd give javascript a go as well, if possible to know the function that does it.

Answer (score 2):

parent css : `{overflow:hidden;}`

edit: specifically :

`<div class='some-tough-edges'>buncho stuffs</div>`

`.some-tough-edges {
width: yourchoice;
height: yourchoice;
overflow: hidden;
//display: block; if not using a block element
}`

edit2 : don't use fixed within the overflow, fixed position the container, and absolute or relative within it

Comment: That wouldn't work because fixed elements position are based on the viewport of the browser, I added here just to prove it though. http://jsfiddle.net/cafgnzj3/1/

Comment: added an edit mention about that. Fixed position the highest parent only ~ if you really must

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to make `.the_content` an absolute element and then use z-index like this:

```
.fixedElement { position: fixed; z-index: 1; }
.the_content { position: absolute; z-index: 2; }
```

If `.the_content` is dynamic, adjust its height and position in Javascript.

It's easier to adjust height and position in Javascript than achieving this very effect in it.